# Movilizer: Can I show numeric keyboard automatically and bypass the ok button?

Tags: java, movilizer

I am working with Movilizer v15 in eclipse neon.

Currently, I am making a quiz, where people need to answer a number of questions with numeric values. But every question now consists of clicking on the answer (attributeType="2") to open the numeric keyboard, followed by answering, closing it again and pressing ok. This get's very tedious after a while.

**So my question:** Is there a way I can bypass opening the keyboard or having to click twice to move on to the next screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can focus an Answer in the onEnterAssignment of a Question. If that Answer is of attributeType="2" this should open the numeric keyboard of the platform right away. If that keyboard allows "tabbing" forward, you can move from input field to input field. I think on Android the standard keyboard can do that.

```
focus(answ-desc answer, str clientKey)
```

Limitations might be

- input fields across complex UIs
- triggering OK event after the last input field is left

Comment: It works good, only downside is that the focus goes pretty slow. Thank you!